# BnB's in Northern Ireland

Tags: bookings

I will be driving from Dublin to Northern Ireland and around the coast to Killarney.  Can you give me tips about driving?  What about just waiting to find a place to stay every day depending on where we are?  Is that a problem in May?

Comment: "Tips about driving" is kind of broad. Where are you used to driving?

Comment: And if you're driving in Ireland, the roads are anything but "broad". Prepare for narrow roads with physics-defying passing experiences!

Comment: Northern Ireland is miles per hour, Republic of Ireland is kilometres per hour

Comment: And your questions about accommodation are basically matters of opinion, which doesn't really work in the Stack Exchange format. There's guidance about how to ask good questions in our [help] and our short site [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I've done a full-circuit road trip around the island, from Dublin to Waterford, Cork, Dingle, Moher, Galway, Sligo, Giants Causeway, Belfast and back to Dublin.  We stayed in hostels and mostly arrived without a booking.  We were travelling in September.

Driving was pretty much hassle-free, except when we got hit by a toilet falling off a truck on the highway!  Irish humour!  Obviously if you're just driving between the main towns the roads are going to be fine.

Given the fickle nature of Irish weather, I'd recommend that you stay as flexible as possible with your travel plans, or at least book accommodation that has free cancellation.